# Можно ли получить userid у сообщения

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу парсер сообщений из чата под конкретного пользователя, использую `TLSharp`, вопрос в том, можно ли как нибудь узнать к какому пользователю принадлежит конкретное сообщение?

```
TLInputPeerChannel inputPeer = new TLInputPeerChannel()
{
    ChannelId = channel.Id,
    AccessHash = (long)channel.AccessHash
};

while (true)
{
    TLChannelMessages res = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLChannelMessages>
    (new TLRequestGetHistory()
    {
        Peer = inputPeer,
        Limit = 400,
        AddOffset = offset,
        OffsetId = 0,
    });
    var msgs = res.Messages;
```